# telerik combobox rendering issue (shadow issue)

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, telerik

Telerik combobox was working very well. I didnt made any change, but it is not rendering properly now. https://snag.gy/mXYTU7.jpg 
It is seen like it has a shadow and reflection. What causes this problem and how can I solve it?

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-6 col-md-push-4">
        <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server"  ID="cmbUser">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is basic combobox and I dont change its properties in codebehind.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior on my side. What version of the control are you using?

Comment: @PierreLebon 2017.1.118.45 is written in properties as version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RadComboBox in classic render mode uses sprite images to display backgrounds and borders in all skins that have rounded borders and gradients. The reason is supporting the control also in old browser. It's recommended to use lightweight render mode.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox RenderMode="Lightweight"  />
```

Sometimes other render mode on the page , even in master page can disturb the display. But this could be a different story as it will imply to set a render mode for the whole solution and hunt down every occurrence of render mode properties.  This usually happen with Rad Check box but have been patch in an update.

So add RenderMode Lightweight. Update the solution.

Comment: Master page caused the problem, it was CSS problem, but thanks for your reply. Also rendermode is very useful, I applied in a button. Thanks